# Prove that the sequence $\{a_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

> Suppose that a bounded sequence $\{a_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ is such that $$a_{n + 2} \leq \dfrac {1} {3} a_{n+1} + \dfrac {2} {3} a_n,\ \ \ \ \text {for}\ n \geq 1$$ Prove that the sequence $\{a_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ is convergent.

What I find is that for all $n \geq 1,$ we have $$a_{n + 2} - a_2 \leq \dfrac {2} {3} (a_1 - a_{n+1}).$$

Also it can't be eventually monotone increasing since for otherwise for all $n \geq 1,$ we have $$a_{n+2} - a_{n+1} \leq \dfrac {2} {3} (a_n - a_{n+1}) \leq 0 \implies a_{n+2} \leq a_{n+1},$$ a contradiction. So if the sequence is eventually monotone it has to be eventually monotone decreasing.

Is it of any importance? Thanks.

Comment: What are the restrictions on $a_{1}$?

Comment: The sequence given by $a_n=\begin{cases}2^{-n}&n>1\\\frac18&n=1\end{cases}$ seems to fit and is not monotone

Comment: @Derek Luna no restriction has been given sir.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen sir the sequence you have provided is eventually monotone decreasing and bounded below by $0$ and hence convergent. Am I right?

Comment: I know that. But I think you agree that eventually monotone bounded sequences are convergent @metamorphy and what has been asked to prove that the sequence is convergent (may be the author means to say that the sequence is eventually monotone). If you want I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @metamorphy fixed it now. Thanks.

Comment: The sequence $0,1,0,\frac23,0,\frac 49,0,\frac 8{27},\ldots$  is not even *eventually* monotone.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen sir but the cool thing what I observe is that the sequence you have just provided is also convergent. What's the logic behind it?

Comment: @VIVID it is indeed convergent because the odd (all the $0$'s) and even $\left ( \left (\frac {2} {3} \right )^{n-1} \right )$ subsequences both converge to $0.$ Look carefully!

Comment: @Phibetakappa Of course it is convergent. But that was not the question

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen sir I want to know why is it always convergent regardless of what sequence we are going to take  satisfying the given recurrence relation? Although the question is wrongly posed. This question is actually given to me by one of my friends. I tried it for almost an hour but couldn't show the monotoneness or at least eventually monotoneness. That's why I posted it in this site to get some help. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @Phibetakappa That is a valid question, but different from the oriignal question whic specifically wants us to show eventual monotnoy first

Comment: I apologize for that. Please don't mind. Should I delete the question or edit it accordingly? Thanks again @Hagen von Eitzen sir.

Comment: I think **edit** is the better choice.

Comment: Fixed it @metamorphy. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $c>0$ determined below, let $b_n=a_{n+1}+ca_n$. Then $\{b_n\}_{n\ge1}$ is also bounded from below and we obtain
$$b_{n+1}=a_{n+2}+ca_{n+1}\le \left(\frac13+c\right)a_{n+1}+\frac23 a_n=\frac{(1+3c)a_{n+1}+2a_n}{3}.$$
If we smartly pick $c=\frac23$, this amounts to
$$ b_{n+1}\le b_n.$$
We conclude that sequence $b_n$ converges to some limit $b$.

By applying $\liminf$ to both sides of the equation $a_{n+1}=b_n-\frac23 a_n$, we find
$$\tag1\liminf a_n=b-\frac23\limsup a_n $$
and similarly
$$\tag2\limsup a_n=b-\frac23\liminf a_n.$$
Solving the linear equations  $(1)$ and $(2)$, we arrive at
$$ \liminf a_n=\limsup a_n=\frac 53 b,$$
i.e.,
$$\lim a_n=\frac 53 b. $$

Comment: $\lim a_n = \dfrac {3} {5} b.$ Am I right sir?

Comment: May I know sir what's the thought process behind constructing the sequence $\{b_n \}_{n \geq 1}$?